# m4 how to detect if you're compiling for x86?

Tags: gcc, m4

(ps when i say `x86` i also mean `x86_64`)
i'm working on a project that may be compiled for several different platforms, and i have some x86-specific files that should only be added when i'm compiling against x86 (as opposed to ARM or anything else)

basically looking for something like

```
IS_X86([
    dnl compiling for x86
], [
    dnl compiling for something other than x86
])
```

so.. how do i detect if i'm compiling for x86 in m4?

Comment: Consider using [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) and/or [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp). You might [popen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) the output of `gcc -v`

Answer (score 0):

Edit: per the comments, this is apparently a GNU Autoconf solution, not a pure M4 solution (personally i barely know M4 and barely know Autoconf, i didn't even know this was autoconf-specific code)

here's what i came up with in the end.. seems to work, so unless anyone has a better suggestion,

```
dnl
dnl PHP_CHECK_X86_TARGET
dnl
dnl check if we're compiling for x86/x86_64
dnl
AC_DEFUN([PHP_CHECK_X86_TARGET], [
  AC_CACHE_CHECK([for x86 target],ac_cv_target_x86,[
  AC_RUN_IFELSE([AC_LANG_SOURCE([[
int main(void) {
#if defined(__x86_64__) || defined(__i386__)
    return 0;
#else
    return 1;
#endif
}
]])],[
  ac_cv_target_x86=yes
],[
  ac_cv_target_x86=no
],[
  ac_cv_target_x86=no
])])
])


dnl
dnl PHP_CHECK_WINDOWS_TARGET
dnl
dnl check if we're compiling for windows
dnl
AC_DEFUN([PHP_CHECK_WINDOWS_TARGET], [
  AC_CACHE_CHECK([for windows target],ac_cv_target_windows,[
  AC_RUN_IFELSE([AC_LANG_SOURCE([[
int main(void) {
#if defined(_WIN32)
    return 0;
#else
    return 1;
#endif
}
]])],[
  ac_cv_target_windows=yes
],[
  ac_cv_target_windows=no
],[
  ac_cv_target_windows=no
])])
])


dnl
dnl PHP_CHECK_UNIX_TARGET
dnl
dnl check if we're compiling for a unix-ish target
dnl
AC_DEFUN([PHP_CHECK_UNIX_TARGET], [
  AC_CACHE_CHECK([for unix-ish target],ac_cv_target_unix,[
  AC_RUN_IFELSE([AC_LANG_SOURCE([[
int main(void) {
#if defined(unix) || defined(__unix) || defined(__unix__)
    return 0;
#else
    return 1;
#endif
}
]])],[
  ac_cv_target_unix=yes
],[
  ac_cv_target_unix=no
],[
  ac_cv_target_unix=no
])])
])
```

Comment: If you are using GNU autoconf, you should have tagged them. Neither your question, nor tags indicate you are using autoconf, which suggest you _want_ a pure m4 solution. Pure m4 solution could be similar, with `syscmd` running gcc and executing a program and then getting with `sysval` the exit status.

Comment: @KamilCuk sorry, i didn't even know i was writing autoconf-specific code above, and my knowledge of M4 (and autoconf) is very limited.. what do you think i should do? keep the question open and wait for someone to post a "pure m4 solution" ? or tag autoconf? or .. idk

Comment: No worries - tag autoconf and accept your answer. ;) `i didn't even know` - it's easy to know - `AC_*` stuff is from AutoConf.